# Java Generics - List<?> vs List<T>

Tags: java, generics

Consider the following 2 alternate APIs:

```
void method(List<?> list)
<T> void method(List<T> list)
```

I know that their internal implementation will have many differences to deal with, such as `List<?>` wont be able to write into the list etc.

Also, in my knowledge `List<?>` will allow any parameterized type with `List` as base type. So will be the case with `List<T>` also.

Can anybody tell me if there is any difference at all in what kinds of inputs these 2 APIs will accept. (NOT the 2 APIs internal implementation differences.)

Comment: I believe they'll accept exactly the same input. The limitations of `<?>` only appear when you try to work with the list and the type is relevant for some reason.

Comment: I think `List<?>` only adds the information that no element will be added to the list (except for `null`s)

Answer (score 3):

The *internal* implementation is exactly the same. In fact, both methods compiled with `javac` will yield equal method byte code, if they compile at all).

However, during compilation, the first method is specified to *not care* about the component type of the list, while the second requires that the component type be *invariant*. This means that whenever I call such a method, the component type of `list` will be fixed by whatever the call site uses.

I can call my method with a `List<String>` and `T` will be synonymous to `String` during the call (from the perspective of the compiler). I can also call it with a `List<Runnable>` and `T` will be synonymous to `Runnable` during the call.

Note that your method does not return anything, but it very well could do so depending on the arguments. Consider the method:

```
<T> T findFirst(Collection<T> ts, Predicate<T> p) { … }
```

You can use this method for each `T`. **BUT** it only works if our `T` is equal for the collection and predicate — this is what "invariance" means. You could in fact specify the method to be applicable in more contexts:

```
<T> T findFirst(Collection<? extends T> ts, Predicate<? super T> p) { … }
```

This method would work the same as above, but it would be more lenient in what types it accepts. Consider a type hierarchy `A extends B extends C`. Then you could call:

```
Collection<A> cs = …;
Predicate<C> p = …;
B b = findFirst(cs, p);
```

We call the type of `ts` *covariant* and the type of `p` (in the method signature) *contravariant*.

Wildcards (`?`) are a different matter. They can be bounded (like in our cases above) to be co- or contravariant. If they are unbounded, the compiler actually needs a concrete type to fill in at compile time (which is why you will sometimes get errors like "type wildcard-#15 is not a match for wildcard-#17"). The specific rules are laid out in the [Java Language Specification, Section 4.5.1](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-4.html#jls-4.5.1).

Comment: Could you please elaborate a bit more on your 2nd paragraph?

Comment: I just extended my answer.

Comment: Thanks but, You are not not talking about List<?> specifically yet.  In my understanding all the things you told about List<T> above will still be applicable to List<?> from a caller's point of view. I was looking for the differences as seen by the caller.